# Get Todays date and go back 27 months show in dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a reporting app and I need to go back 27 months of the current date and show in a dropdown as a filter. What is the best way to accomplish this using React?

example:
if today is:
March 27, 2022
I need to go back 27 months to
Feb 2020  - and this has to be the first selection in the drop down

Comment: First of all, if today is March 1, 2022, 27 months back is Dec 1, 2019.

Comment: @JustWantsToCode visit this link https://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/rLjQx/  and try the below code inside it ```var now = moment(new Date("01-03-2022")).subtract(27, "months").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
alert(now);```  you will get it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) subtract method in order to do that.

Eg: `var startdate = moment(new Date()).subtract(27, "months").format("DD-MM-YYYY");`

this will take today's date and subtracts 27 months to it.

And in order to show that in dropdown just use a state from react and add the default value / value to the dropdown.

Also note when decimal values are passed for days and months, they are rounded to the nearest integer. You can refer their documentation for more info.